# Spring mvc ModelAndView occur 404 Error

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelandview

Using OSX, Spring mvc 4, intellij

I want to use `ModelAndView`.
When I enter server/board/showArticleList, It shows 404 Error like below.
And server doesn't show any error.

Error message in browser

```
Type Status Report

Message /WEB-INF/views/board/showArticleList.jsp

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/board/showArticleList")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
                                  HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setView("test");
    modelAndView.addObject("title", "this is title");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testPage</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${title}
</body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="Controller"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of view in setview and RequestMapping are not matching so Dispatcher Servlet is unable to resolve the view.

Comment: How can you bypass it not changing the mapping?

Comment: Just change the jsp filename to match the mapping